Kubernetes Ingress to domain
I'm new to kubernetes, actually I started 1 week ago and I'm trying to use Ingress to see the application using a domain name but no matter what I've done I haven't been able to get it to work. My yaml file has the following format and when I apply it, it runs normally and doesn't show me any errors.
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: my-namespace
  
---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app-deployment
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-app-service
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    nodePort: 32000
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80

---

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-app-ingress
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: xxxx.xxxxxx.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx-service
            port:
              number: 80

When I try to browse the application using the nodePort http://??.??.??.??:32000/ I can view the contents of the application but when I use the domain name I get the error message "This site can’t be reached".
I have spent too many hours and I can't find what the problem is. Can someone tell me what is wrong with my configuration.
Thanks in advance

Based on the YAML configuration you've posted, there appears to be a mismatch between the service name specified in the Ingress resource and the actual name of the service defined earlier in your configuration. In my opinion, this is likely why your domain name is not resolving correctly to your application hosted on Kubernetes.
Your service is defined with the name my-app-service, however, in your Ingress definition, you are referencing a service named nginx-service.
To fix the issue, update the Ingress resource to match the correct service name:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-app-ingress
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: xxxx.xxxxxx.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-app-service  # Here
            port:
              number: 80

Make sure to apply the updated configuration with kubectl apply -f <filename>.yaml. Also, ensure that your DNS settings for xxxx.xxxxxx.com are correctly pointing to your Kubernetes cluster's external IP where the Ingress controller is running.

You need to change the service name in your Ingress yaml file to match the name of the actual service you created.
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: xxxx.xxxxxx.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-app-service  # Changed this from "nginx-service"
            port:
              number: 80

